# PHPBrew - various problems with installation

Tags: php, linux, phpbrew

I am trying to install PHP 5.4 with PHPBrew but have those errors:

```
-> % phpbrew install 5.4.6 +default +apxs2 +mysql                              
===> phpbrew will now build 5.4.6
===> Loading and resolving variants...
Checking distribution checksum...
Checksum matched: c9aa0f4996d1b91ee9e45afcfaeb5d2e
===> Distribution file was successfully extracted, skipping...
Found existing Makefile, running make clean to ensure everything will be rebuilt.
You can append --no-clean option after the install command if you don't want to rebuild.
===> Running make clean: /usr/bin/make -C '/home/breq/.phpbrew/build/php-5.4.6' --quiet 'clean'
===> Checking patches...
Checking patch for replace apache php module name with custom version name
0 changes patched.
Found existing build.log, renaming it to /home/breq/.phpbrew/build/php-5.4.6/build.log.1466515643
===> Configuring 5.4.6...


Use tail command to see what's going on:
   $ tail -F /home/breq/.phpbrew/build/php-5.4.6/build.log


===> Checking patches...
Checking patch for php5.3.29 multi-sapi patch.
Checking patch for php5.3.x on 64bit machine when intl is enabled.
Checking patch for openssl dso linking patch
===> Building...
Error: Make failed:
The last 5 lines in the log file:
/home/breq/.phpbrew/build/php-5.4.6/ext/openssl/xp_ssl.c:355: undefined reference to `SSLv3_server_method'

/home/breq/.phpbrew/build/php-5.4.6/ext/openssl/xp_ssl.c:343: undefined reference to `SSLv3_client_method'

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Makefile:244: recipe for target 'sapi/cli/php' failed

make: *** [sapi/cli/php] Error 1

Please checkout the build log file for more details:
     tail /home/breq/.phpbrew/build/php-5.4.6/build.log
```

With `+openssl`

```
-> % phpbrew install 5.4.6 +default +apxs2 +mysql +openssl=/usr/include/openssl
===> phpbrew will now build 5.4.6
===> Loading and resolving variants...
Checking distribution checksum...
Checksum matched: c9aa0f4996d1b91ee9e45afcfaeb5d2e
===> Distribution file was successfully extracted, skipping...
Found existing Makefile, running make clean to ensure everything will be rebuilt.
You can append --no-clean option after the install command if you don't want to rebuild.
===> Running make clean: /usr/bin/make -C '/home/breq/.phpbrew/build/php-5.4.6' --quiet 'clean'
===> Checking patches...
Checking patch for replace apache php module name with custom version name
0 changes patched.
Found existing build.log, renaming it to /home/breq/.phpbrew/build/php-5.4.6/build.log.1466516015
===> Configuring 5.4.6...


Use tail command to see what's going on:
   $ tail -F /home/breq/.phpbrew/build/php-5.4.6/build.log


Error: Configure failed:
The last 5 lines in the log file:
checking for Kerberos support... no

checking for DSA_get_default_method in -lssl... no

checking for X509_free in -lcrypto... yes

checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config

configure: error: Cannot find OpenSSL's <evp.h>

Please checkout the build log file for more details:
     tail /home/breq/.phpbrew/build/php-5.4.6/build.log
```

My OS: `Xubuntu 16.10` + `PHP 7.07`

```
-> % tail /home/lmalicki/.phpbrew/build/php-5.4.6/build.log
checking whether to enable LIBXML support... yes
checking libxml2 install dir... /usr
checking for xml2-config path... /usr/bin/xml2-config
checking whether libxml build works... yes
checking for OpenSSL support... yes
checking for Kerberos support... no
checking for DSA_get_default_method in -lssl... no
checking for X509_free in -lcrypto... yes
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
configure: error: Cannot find OpenSSL's <evp.h>
```

Answer (score 0):

I look like you're missing some dependencies.

Try with install ssl dev package first:

```
apt-get install libssl-dev
```

PHPBrew just downloads and compiles php, but it doesn't install required dependecies in your OS.

**EDIT:**

I've just noticed that you've provided path for openssl library in `+openssl=/usr/include/openssl`.

Are you sure it's there? You can check it with `which openssl`. This command will return the path of openssl binary.

Also you may try to simply remove the path, since PHPBrew should find proper binary on it's own.

Comment: -> % sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libssl-dev is already the newest version (1.0.2h-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 40 not upgraded.

Answer (score 0):

Since +openssl directive is actually providing a prefix not an include path, try

```
+openssl=/usr -- --with-libdir=lib64
```

Comment: with this solution I'm having: checking for Kerberos support... no

checking for DSA_get_default_method in -lssl... no

checking for X509_free in -lcrypto... yes

checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config

configure: error: Cannot find OpenSSL's libraries

Comment: Can you paste whole build log not just last 10 lines including the configure command?

Answer (score 0):

```
configure: error: Cannot find OpenSSL's <evp.h>
```

This problem may happen if you have newer version of OpenSSL installed then your distribution provided.

If you use ubuntu you may need to downgrade your packages back. ( but probably you have installed a different version for a reason so be careful here )

```
#file etc/apt/preferences.d/allow-downgrade

Package: *
Pin: release o=Ubuntu
Pin-Priority: 1001
```

then

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

and options

```
 -- --with-openssl=/path/to/libs
```

or

```
+openssl
```

should work just fine.

If you already have some misfunctioning PHP installed from PHPbrew don't forget to switch with

```
phpbrew switch recently_installed_php_ver_number_here
```

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 16.10

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev
sudo apt-get install clibcurl4-openssl-dev pkg-config libssl-dev libsslcommon2-dev
```

then re-run

```
phpbrew install 5.4.6 +default +apxs2 +mysql +openssl=/usr/include/openssl
```